# JWT angular spring boot. checking authentication for user null

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt, angular2-jwt

I have a problem when consuming services with a token using JWT.
When I consume the service to obtain the token, it works perfectly and I return the token to consume the services, but when sending the headers it does not work correctly and it returns error 401. I have looked many times at the source code, and I do not see any error about it .

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoordinadoresService {

  private static BASEURL:string = "http://localhost:8080/coordinador/";
  private static BASEURLTOKEN:string = "http://localhost:8080/auth";

  token:string = "";

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  headers(){
    this.token = sessionStorage.getItem("Token");
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': this.token });
    return headers;
  }

  getServices(url:string): Promise<any> {
    this.token = sessionStorage.getItem("Token");
    let header = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': this.token });
    return this.http.get(CoordinadoresService.BASEURL + url,{headers:header})
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            return response;
        })
        .catch(err => err);
  }

 postServicesToken(data:any): Promise<any> {
    let header = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http.post(CoordinadoresService.BASEURLTOKEN,data,{headers:header})
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            return response;
        })
        .catch(err => err);
  }

}
```

In spring boot in console it appears that a null user arrives:

[image]

[image]

[image]

in postman the services work without any problem, sending the token in the header. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

thanks for your help

Comment: could you display how the request looks in the browser network log?

Comment: Sure, look. It does not generate any response. I attached images

Comment: If it works in postman then you should check the actual request in developers tools network tab. It should contain the header.